# Draw an aligned edge

Tags: graphviz, neato

Considering the following graph:

```
digraph {
  node[shape=square style=filled];
  A [color=olivedrab4   fillcolor=olivedrab3];
  B [color=orange3      fillcolor=orange];
  C [color=royalblue4   fillcolor=royalblue];
  D [color=orangered3   fillcolor=orangered];

      edge[arrowhead=none];
  node[shape=circle];
  u -> v -> w -> {x y}

  A -> u;
  B -> v;
  C -> y;
  D -> x;

  edge[arrowhead=normal];
  splines=true;
  sep=1;
  A -> D [len=100];
  A -> C [len=100];
}
```

which `neato` renders like this:

[image]

is it possible to draw the edges from `A` to `D` (and `A` to `C`) in a way that the spline is  aligned to the path `A-u-v-w-x-D` (and `A-u-v-w-y-C` respectively)?

**Background:** I'd like to draw overlays, situated above underlay network topologies.

Digging around in the source code i found the `pathplan` library (which seems to be used by at least `neato`).

To quote from `lib/pathplan/README`:

> Our plan is to clean up the
>   internal interfaces (where data structures are copied and converted
>   so we could glue in some older code).  We also changed the spline
>   fitter router so that the output spline is not forced to hit all the
>   points of the input path.  We plan to extend the library interface to
>   let the caller determine which path points must be hit.

That sounds somewhat like what i want...